# how to read the whole web page with Python - bs4 /response read only first part of the page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the page to get the term and its definition from the page https://dictionary.apa.org/caffeine-intoxication (or similar pages at dictionary.apa.org)

The following code (and bs4 too) gets only `<head>` part of the page (only html part?, 'save as html' in a browser gives the same result):

```
import requests
url = 'https://dictionary.apa.org/a-posteriori'
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(response.text)
```

But I really need to get other elements of the page (`<body>`):

```
<terms><term><dt><a href="/caffeine-intoxication"><h4>
<hw>caffeine intoxication</hw>
</h4></a></dt><dd>in <em>DSM–IV–TR</em> and <em>DSM–5</em>, intoxication due to recent consumption of large amounts of caffeine (typically over 250 mg), in the form of coffee, tea, cola, or medications, and involving at least five of the following symptoms: restlessness, nervousness, excitement, insomnia, flushed face, diuresis (increased urination), gastrointestinal complaints, muscle twitching, rambling thought and speech, rapid or irregular heart rhythm, periods of inexhaustibility, or psychomotor agitation. Also called <span style="font-family:arial;font-weight:bold">caffeinism</span>.</dd></term></terms>
```

How can I get the rest of the page?

Answer (score 1):

This data is not coming from the host domain...
try this:

```
res = requests.get('https://4hb3d9itb2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/getdopdefinitions?q=a-posteriori')
sp = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
sp.find_all('terms')
```

output:

```
[<terms><term><dt><a href="/a-posteriori"><h4>
 <hw>a posteriori</hw>
 </h4></a></dt><dd>denoting conclusions derived from observations or other manifest occurrences: reasoning from facts. Compare <a href="/a-priori">a priori</a>. [Latin, âfrom the latterâ]</dd></term></terms>]
```

Note that 'lxml' is my preferred parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just missed that that the domain is different - by the way - where was the link? was it available in the Inspect Element?

Comment: Not in inspect element. For future, I usually I browse the network tab to see where the data is coming from. This is how I found the correct url to call.

Comment: Pointed well out, that content is provided via API - Just in addition to your parser comment. It is bs4 standard parser, so  it is not necessary to write it out `BeautifulSoup(res.text)` is doing exactly the same job. anyway +1

Comment: Good to know, I always thought BS used html.parse as default.